# Problem in ASP.NET to throw an error and catch it in the global.asax

Tags: asp.net

In an aspx web page I'm doing this:

```
Try

    Throw new IndexOutOfRangeException

Catch ex As Exception

    Dim myException As New bizException(ex)

    Throw myException

End Try
```

In the global.asax I'm doing this:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim myException As bizException = DirectCast(Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException(), bizException)


End Sub
```

An this error is occuring during the cast:

InvalidCastException:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' to type 'bizException'.

The GetLastError's type is IndexOutOfRangeException and not bizException... Why ?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Application_Error" routine, Server.GetLastError() returns exceptions of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' because you did not handle the error earlier - i.e. at method or page level.

You need to examine the contents of "InnerException" from the exception returned by Server.GetLastError().

The "InnerException" will contain your "bizException".

`Dim myException As bizException = DirectCast(Server.GetLastError().InnerException, bizException)`

Not sure of the VB.NET syntax here - more of a C# person myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Dim myException As bizException = DirectCast(Server.GetLastError(), bizException)
```

(Removed "GetBaseException" call.)

Comment: daughtkom:

I got a different error message:
    
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' to type 'bizException'.